# Make assignment in list comprehension

Tags: python, python-3.x, list-comprehension

How can I move this code to list comprehension

```
prev = 0
data = [1, 20, 40, 50, 100]
newlist = []
for x in data: 
    value = x - prev 
    prev = x 
    newlist.append(value)
```

Comment: This is very similar to a [recent tweet](https://twitter.com/raymondh/status/1198360907908182017).

Comment: yes, I am actually studying this at the moment, good catch :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Instead of using a `prev` variable, just make a new list that starts with 0.

```
[x-prev for prev, x in zip([0]+data, data)]
```

You probably shouldn't use this for large `data` though, since it makes a whole new copy. You can use itertools.chain to make this faster:

```
[x - prev for prev, x in zip(chain([0], data), data)]
```

Answer (score 0):

@Keatinge's answer is good. Here's another version that doesn't make any copies. Technically not a list comprehension: the `*(...)` extends the list literal with items from the generator inside.

```py
[data[0], *(data[i + 1] - data[i] for i in range(len(data) - 1))]
```